# How to know text lengh in EditView

Tags: android

How do i know the text lengh when i typing on the EditText.

this is my codes below.

I tried getting the lengh of EditText by using getText

but i connot control it to attch the other text.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
```

I uesd

> OnKeyListener

in my code but It's not clear for me.

so I'm looking for other solution ~ to solve it.

What should i do for this?

Comment: have you tried `et.length()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use OnKeyListener, you can use TextWacher that is listener for EditText while you typing on the EditText.

If you typing on it even 1 letter, afterTextChanged will be called. so you can know how length it is by using s.getText.length().

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.getText.length() > 5){
                // do something you want
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

et.length() give you the length